# jquery split string not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get some values from the url in the page. I'm not getting an array but a comma separated string. It works on the console but not on the site.

this is the url:

```
mysite.com/index.html?tags=tag2+tag1
```

This is my html header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="home_recipes_js.php"></script>
```

This is the js code:

```
checkDocumentReady();

function checkDocumentReady() {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var tagsString = getUrlVars()["tags"];

        tagsParser(tagsString);
    });
}

function getUrlVars() {

    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

function tagsParser(tagsString) {

    var rawTags = tagsString.split('+');

    console.log('rawTags : ' + rawTags.length + ' ' + rawTags);
}
```

this is the console output:

```
tagsString: 2 tag2,tag1
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. See anwser below. If you want to output individual items in the array use indexes: `rawTags[0]` will give you first value in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
console.log(rawTags);
```

You will get an array.

When JavaScript concatenates an array to a string, **it actually calls `.join(',')` on the array**, so in your code

```
console.log('rawTags : ' + rawTags.length + ' ' + rawTags);
```

the **interpreter translates it into**

```
console.log('rawTags : ' + rawTags.length + ' ' + rawTags.join(','));
```

that is why you are getting a string at the end. Otherwise your code is fine.

Even then you want to see it as an array in the same way use **[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** on the array, like:

```
console.log('rawTags : ' + rawTags.length + ' ' + JSON.stingify(rawTags));
```

it will keep the bracket notation but it won't be an array literally.

Comment: It works, I was expecting to see the array in the log string :) Thanks! This was driving me crazy